# gun db storage model for large centrally stored data, tiny collaborative clients

Tags: gun

**Use Case:**

Say I wanted to create a realtime-collaborative document editing system.

In this scenario many users could create and collaborate on many documents.

Due to client-device constraints, it's not possible for any client to keep a replica of all documents, only just a handful.

There needs to be central storage server where all documents always live, and this server is always backed up.

Each client can 'subscribe' to any document, and all clients subscribed can see realtime changes of all other clients subscribed/editing the same document.

**Questions:**

Since each client can't store all documents, there needs to be a way to remove the replicas of 'old' documents from the client, without deleting the document from the central store, ideally based on an automatic least-recently-used approach. How is this handled in gun?

In gun, how can a document be deleted from the central store, so it's then effectively permanently removed from, and no longer accessible to, all clients?

When a document is deleted from the central store, how is the physical storage space ever actually reclaimed for later use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great questions, @user2672083 . Here is the current lay out:

1. Collaborative realtime document editing is possible with gun. Here is a [quick prototype](https://youtu.be/rci89p0o2wQ) I recorded a long time ago, however there are no full pre-built examples/implementations yet.
2. Not all data is stored on every client by default. The browser only keeps the data it requests/gets/subscribes to.
3. The default server already acts as a backup. I recommend using the S3 storage adapter, because then you do not have to worry about running out of disk space.
4. Removing old replicas. Currently, if I want the server to act as a central "master", I just put a `localStorage.clear()` at the top of my browser code. This will force the browser to have to always load the latest from the server. This is not ideal though, an LRU specific feature is coming soon according to the [roadmap](https://github.com/amark/gun/wiki/Roadmap).
5. Permanently removing data and reclaiming space. While this should be easy for a central setup, because gun is P2P by default, it uses a technique called [tombstoning to delete](https://github.com/amark/gun/wiki/delete) data. Given a lot of requests (like yours) for LRU/TTL/GC/deleting, there will be better support for this in the future. Currently, you have to use a mix of `rm data.json`, `localStorage.clear()` and 30 day lifecycles on S3 to get this to work. This will be more integrated/easier in the future.

Now a question for you: What are you working on, and how can I help? Many of the things you asked about are possible (with some work) now, but slated to be the focus of the next version of gun - I'd love to get your feedback as we build this out.

---

All peers reply to requests for data (#2), meaning that localStorage and the server will both reply. Because localStorage is physically closer to a user, it will reply first/fastest and then replies from the server will be merged. GUN does not try each peer "in sequence" doing try/catch cascades, GUN replies from all peers in parallel.

GUN has swappable storage and transport interfaces, so yes, it is easy to build other layers on top or into it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Re#2 & #4, when a browser is reopened wouldn't get's always end up contacting active peers anyways? If so, `localStorage.clear()` wouldn't hurt, but shouldn't be called if can't connect to 'master' peer? Re#3, if all clients were gone, then the server would be a single copy, which is not a backup; ideally a true backup would simply be another gun peered to server, but in effect would receive all changes happening on master? Further, or use case requires supporting Azure, Google, other cloud providers, and internal deployments

Comment: We're currently using Firebase, along with Druid & ElasticSearch. We're looking to replace Firebase. Having looked a little bit deeper into gun code, it would seem that, conceptually, the 'storage' interface gun sits on top of could be better defined and abstracted. Then it could talk to a 'client' or 'server' implementations, who would handle the lifecyle of things, themselves using the same interface to then sit on top of actual storage providers. Is this refactoring something we can assist with and contribute to gun?

Comment: @user2672083 replied by editing the answer :) re: Azure/GCS you can already deploy to them now, and it should be trivial to copy gun's S3 adapter/driver and replace it with Azure/GCS Blob Store API - or we can build this for you easily (shoot an email to enterprise [AT] gunDB [DOT] io for pricing). Same with the storage/abstraction layers, GUN has a simple wire spec that makes it easy for new/swappable drivers/adapters that we can build for you. Let me know!

Comment: @marknadal Is there a way to know how many peers are subscribed to a certain graph?